# Is something like this valid at all- div.find and input id

Tags: jquery

Hello I have something like

```
 div.find("input").autocomplete({
```

.....

and am wondering if I can add an input id to the element...

ie.

```
 div.find("input#good")
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An input tag can have an id on it like: `<input id="good" type="text">`.  If you did that, then you can just use this jQuery `$("#good")` to find it and that should be simpler than `div.find("input#good")` and faster because finding an id is natively supported by the browser.

There can only be one object in a page with the id="good", so there's no reason to use div.find on it unless you only want it found if it's in a more narrow context.

Comment: Using `input#good` would make sense if a script was going to be used on several pages and some of those pages had `#good` that wasn't an `<input>`. But, if you were dealing with something like that then a class would probably be a better call; OTOH, quick fixes, getting paid, etc. Using `$x.find()` would make sense if `$x` wasn't yet in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("input[name=inputname]");` instead. Getting values will be easier later down the road if you reference them like that.

oh and your inputs need a name attribute: `<input type="text" name="inputname" />` so that you can use them for actual forms.

Answer (score 0):

Just $("#good") will be enough and this is assuming you have unique id on the page to all the dom elements which have ids.